# How to store cipher text in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, cryptography, pycrypto

I am working on a `Cryptography Application` in Django 1.8 and trying to store `Cipher Text` in my model field. Below is my `Message` model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    encrypted_message = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    hashed_message = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user_id)
```

I am using the following [pycrypto](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/crypto/) module in Python to encrypt the message and store the cipher text in my Django Model.

Code for Encryption and Decryption is here:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
# Encryption

encryption_suite = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456')
cipher_text = encryption_suite.encrypt("Life is Beautiful")

# Decryption

decryption_suite = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456')
plain_text = decryption_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
```

Now suppose `User` enters a message `My life is Beautiful`, then you can see the encrypted message will be:

```
'encrypted_message':
> u'\ufffdH\x060\ufffd!W\ufffdooK8\ufffdg\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd',
```

> {'message': u'Life is beautiful ', 'user_name': ,
>   'encrypted_message':
>   u'\ufffdH\x060\ufffd!W\ufffdooK8\ufffdg\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd',
>   'hashed_message':
>   u'8ada92984f1fc55010c4d2fa38d0fba499691bc746f83eff089ba5212a65f083a947aa1fe6209f05278a5dc7ee12b361'}

But the problem is when I am storing this `Cipher Text` inside my model, it is coming out be some weird characters which I cannot `decrypt` again. Could anyone help me how can I store `cipher text` inside my model field and then `decrypt` it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `base64.b64encode()` and `base64.b64decode()` to bring the hypertext into a readable form that will not break HTML forms.

Comment: `'str' object has no attribute 'base64'` getting this error!

Comment: I am thinking to convert the cipher text into `hexcode` and save into my database. But the problem is how will reconvert `hexcode` into cipher text for decryption?

Comment: `base64` unresolved reference? Do i need to import something?

Comment: You have to import it.

Comment: Okay `import base64` is there.

Comment: It is working but decryption is not giving the original string. Result of decryption -  я"
�3�O���`+
�U�<����5�<�L��{

Comment: I just saw: you have been using two different AES modes. That can't work.

Comment: My bad! Edited the question. I am using CFB mode in both

Comment: I was making some mistake!! Your suggestion worked :) :) :) Could you elaborate what exactly is base64? Why it is working

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, that uses only 64 safe ASCII characters to represent data. This way it can be shown in web form which usually get problems with non-printable characters.